# Can ping my webpage/domain and access my server via SSH, but not via browser

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, wordpress, ubuntu-18.04

I have a webserver running Ubuntu 18.04 hosting a Wordpress installation that was working fine some time ago. I have not tested the public webpage in some time, but it appears to be down now, even though I can SSH in, SFTP in, and ping it fine.

Even after disabling firewall, restarting apache2 (which is running) etc., no luck.

Running `sudo netstat -plunt | grep apache2`, I get

`tcp6       0      0 :::80                 :::*                    LISTEN      982/apache2`

Running `apache2ctl -S`, I get

```
*:80                   vayalinkal.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:4)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Are you aware netstat only shows web server on ipv6, not ipv4?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to HTTP into a webserver using IPv4 that is only listening on IPv6. Double-Check your servers IP configuration, as *:80 should open a listener on all the adresses.